# iPhone 5 retina display 2x image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

For migrating the iPhone to retina device, we have to prepare the images that has double size resolution and name it with "@2x" so IOS will auto use the 2x image in retina device.

My question is what if I break the rule and create a image as triple size (or bigger than double size) but name it with "@2x" as the Apple regulation state. Will Apple reject my application to be uploaded into AppStore?

The reason what I did like that is when I am setting the background image, I did as below:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"]];
```

In iPhone 5 retina display, the double size image cannot fit properly into background because the height of iPhone 5 is not just double size, it is like double size plus extra pixel. This is why I want to customize the background image to be bigger than double size.

I don't really want to add extra code into my app to manually check the device type and load the respective images since IOS has such better and convinient approach.

My worry is will Apple reject my app in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple will not reject your app if you create images with "wrong" size/resolution. However, it usually doesn't make sense to do so.

The `@2x` is meant to indicate the resolution, and both the iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 5 have the same resolution. The only difference is in the height of the screen.

Also, you should use a `UIImageView` for large background images (better memory management and performance).

Add this to your class file or your project's prefix file:

```
#define deviceIsIPhone5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height == 568 ? YES : NO)
```

And in your `viewDidLoad` (or somewhere similar):

```
if (deviceIsIPhone5) 
{
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-568h@2x.png"];
} 
else
{
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background@2x.png"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the app won't be rejected.

It's not a good method to do like what u have done. When your app runs on non-retina hardware the normal image will be used and whenever you use retina hardware the @2x image will be used automatically.

It's idle to give both images.